# What's the best way to eliminate spiders?

Tags: pest

I recently noticed an uptick in observations of this kind of creature in my basement, especially near paper boxes. I have really no clues of what it is. Spiders? But it looks smaller.

What are these creatures? How can I get rid of them? Is it best to call pesticide company?

Any advice appreciated!

[image]

Comment: A good vacuum? Every home has insects to some extent unless chemicals are heavily used. I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: You'd have a whole lot more insects flying around your home if the spiders didn't get them. Hoover the webs that are in your way & leave the spiders alone. They're not hurting you.

Answer (score 4):

Count the legs. Spiders have 8 legs, two body regions and no antennae. All spiders are carnivorous, which means that they feed on other animals, mainly insects. Spiders are almost all harmless to humans, and quite beneficial. When you kill spiders, the insect population will increase. Do yourself and the planet a favor and let them live.

Answer (score 0):

It just looks like a spider web with other bugs and bits trapped in it. It could have taken months or years for it to look in that state.  The bugs may even be dead by now.

If it's just a few abandoned boxes, then just vacuum and spray it yourself.

If it's really everywhere and you can see the insects crawling everywhere, then it could be a job for a pesticide company.